# Firefox/IE not displaying CSS with Drupal website

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

In Firefox and IE (and maybe others?) it seems that the blocks that are built by drupal aren't having CSS applied to them.

Any help at all would be wonderful, as the issue I'm having is not knowing where the issue lies. The site is http://confluencenter.arizona.edu/.

p.s.
I am very new to CSS and Drupal

Answer (score 0):

It's more like a CSS issue. Your CSS has to be more organize and standard cross browsers. Try not to use "**!important**", because you don't want to over-use it as you will end up causing headaches down when maintaining the site.

Here are some example you can fix. 
Under file "**blocks.css**" line 303.

```
.pane-block-4, .pane-block-5, .pane-upcoming-events, .pane-block-6 {
  width: 31.25% !important;
  min-height: 500px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

Since there are 3 classes on each "div"(panel-pane pane-block pane-block-4), you should use something like this instead

```
#mini-panel-front_blocks .panel-pan {
  width: 31.25%;
  min-height: 500px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Do you manage to see blocks.css loading in Firefox or even Chrome? Cause she posted on stackoverflow and I've suggested her to post it here. I find it very weird: no blocks.css is seen in the source, although my Chrome inspector says it gets data from it (the panels css comes from blocks.css). Firefox doesn't see it at all, nor loading it. CSS aggregation seems OFF.

Comment: the blocks file is located 'http://confluencenter.arizona.edu/sites/all/themes/confluence/css/blocks.css', it actually from your "confluence" theme.

Comment: Can you see it loading in the source, using Firefox?

Comment: Run Corn if you update the theme, and clean cache if your cache is on and updated CSS.

Comment: Could you please, answer my question? Do you see it loading?

Comment: No, I don't see it loading on Firefox and ie.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25217/discussion-between-cocoskin-and-designarti).